# How to simplify solutions for $y'' + 4y = 2 \tan x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The original equation is $$y'' + 4y = 2 \tan x$$

What I did so far:

$$\lambda^2+4 = 0$$

$$\lambda_1 = -2i \quad \lambda_2 = 2i$$

$$y(x) = C_1\cos2x+C_2\sin2x$$

---

Write down the system:

$$\begin{cases} C_1'\cos2x + C_2'\sin2x = 0 \\
2C'_2\cos2 x - 2C_1'\sin2x = 2\tan x \end{cases}$$

---

Applying Krammer's formulas

$$\Delta = \begin{vmatrix}\cos2x & \sin2x \\ 2\cos2x  & -2\sin2x \end{vmatrix} = -2\cos4x$$

$$\Delta_2 = \begin{vmatrix} 0 & \sin2x \\ 2\tan x & -2\sin2x\end{vmatrix} = -2\tan x\sin2x = -4\sin^2x$$

$$\Delta_3 = \begin{vmatrix}\cos2x & 0 \\ 2\cos2x & 2\tan x \end{vmatrix} = -2\cos2x\tan x$$

but when I tried to find solutions I got different expressions which I do not know how to integrate, what is the best way to simplify solutions here to get better integrals?

Comment: I think you might use Variation in Parameters.

Comment: @that's what I actually did :)

Comment: Sorry. I am not familiar with this notation; indeed you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your calculation of $\Delta$.

$$ \Delta = \begin{vmatrix}\cos(2x) &\sin(2x) \\ -2\sin(2x) &2\cos(2x)\end{vmatrix} = 2\cos^2(2x)+2\sin^2(2x) = 2$$

$$ C'_1 = \frac{\Delta_2}{\Delta} = -2\sin^2 x$$

$$ C_1 = -2\int sin^2 x \; dx = \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x) -x$$

$$ C'_2 = \frac{\Delta_3}{\Delta} = -\cos(2x)\tan (x)$$

\begin{align} 
C_2 
&= -\int \cos(2x)\tan (x) \; dx 
=-\int \frac{(2\cos^2 x -1)\sin x}{\cos x} \, dx \\ 
&= \int \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} - \int 2\cos x \sin x\, dx 
= -ln|\cos x| + \cos^2 x
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Mutiply the first equation by $\cos(2x)$ and the second by $\sin(2x)$ and subtract them from each other to get:

$$C_1'\cos^2(2x) + C_2'\cos(2x)\sin(2x) - C_2'\cos(2x)\sin(2x) + C_1'\sin^2(2x) = - \tan(x)\sin(2x)$$

$$C_1' = - 2\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \cos(x)\sin(x) = - 2\sin^2(x) = \cos(2x) - 1$$

This is easily integrable.